# Get data of another function

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Hi everyone need some help, I have read a csv file using with open syntax and I want to use this data to another function. What would be the best way to copy the data of the function.

Here's my code:

```
import csv

def read_csv_file(filename):
    temperatures = []
    fans = []
    modes = []
    louvers = []
    swings = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        for line in csv_reader:
            temperatures.append(line[1])
            fans.append(line[2])
            modes.append(line[3])
            louvers.append(line[4])
            swings.append(line[5])
        return temperatures
        return fans
        return modes
        return louvers
        return swings

def get_feature():

    result = {}
    result['feature'] = [{'feature_name': '', 'ftype': 'section_option', 'group_name': '', 'value': ''}]
    result1 = dict()
    result1 = {'definition':[]}
    read_csv_file(filename)

    print (temperatures)


filename = 'ir_raw.csv'
csv_data = read_csv_file(filename)
```

I want to print my csv file data in the def get_feature(): function. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only return from a function once, so in read_csv_file only the first return statement (return temperatures) is executed. The rest of the data is forgotten.

A simple way to get around this is to throw all of your lists into a tuple and then return the tuple. So in read_csv_file, you would put:

```
data = (temperatures, fans, modes, louvers, swings)
return data
```

Then to use the data later on, you need to save that data to a variable and index it for whichever list you want to print.

A full solution, using your methods, could be:

```
import csv

def read_csv_file(filename):
    temperatures = []
    fans = []
    modes = []
    louvers = []
    swings = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for line in csv_reader:
            temperatures.append(line[1])
            fans.append(line[2])
            modes.append(line[3])
            louvers.append(line[4])
            swings.append(line[5])
        return (temperatures, fans, modes, louvers, swings)

def get_feature(data):
    #... do whatever you plan on doing
    print(data[0]) # for temperatures
    print(data[1]) # for fans
    print(data[2]) # for modes
    print(data[3]) # for louvers
    print(data[4]) # for swings

filename = 'ir_raw.csv'
csv_data = read_csv_file(filename)
get_feature(csv_data)
```

Alternatively, instead of using the CSV module, one could use numpy.genfromtxt or use pandas.read_csv.

Comment: It went well. Thank you for the big help!!